# How to check if Object has empty arrays with underscore.js or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, underscore.js

Is there a "better" way to check if an object has empty arrays (0-*) than this:

```
emptyArr: function() {
        var obj = getObj();
        return obj.abc.length == 0 || obj.def.length == 0 || obj.ghi.length == 0 || obj.jkl.length == 0 …………;
}
```

Edit:
Here is how the object looks like:

```
- Object
  - abc = []
  - def = []
  - ghi = []
  - jkl = []
  - …
```

I want to check if the object contains any empty arrays.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you give an example of how your object looks?

Comment: Can't you loop through them and break out of loop as soon as you hit an empty array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the question "Check if an object has any empty array members"?

If so:

```
function hasEmptyArrays(obj) {
  var emptyArrayMembers = _.filter(obj, function(member) { 
    return _.isArray(member) && _.isEmpty(member)
  });

  return emptyArrayMembers.length > 0;
}
```